# changing the primefaces header style of panel component

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, facelets

how can i set the header style of the p:panel component? i want to set the height of the panel_header div.

```
<p:panel id="panel" 
    toggleSpeed="500" toggleable="true">
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <p:outputPanel style="float:left;">
            <p:commandButton process="@this" id="new"
                oncomplete="dialog.show();" icon="ui-icon-plus" />
            <p:spacer width="15px;" />
        </p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputLabel value="Title" />
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You normally use CSS for styling. Use the `.ui-panel .ui-panel-titlebar` selector. You can find the CSS selectors and all its properties in every bit decent webbrowser developer toolset. In Chrome, IE9 and Firebug, rightclick the titlebar and choose *Inspect Element* or press F12.

Here's an example how it look like in Chrome:

[image]

To start, you could set the `padding` to `0`.

```
.ui-panel .ui-panel-titlebar {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Put this in a `.css` file which you load by `<h:outputStylesheet>` inside `<h:body>`, so that it get loaded *after* PrimeFaces default CSS.

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my case there is a different situation.

This panel is in a composite component. And I don't want to change all headers. If I do that you said; all of the headers will be changed. I only want to change the style in the composite component.

Comment: Then just use a more specific CSS selector? E.g. the ID selector. Just to be sure, have you never used CSS before? Have you really never learnt basic HTML/CSS/JS before beginning with JSF? Then I can better calculate what kind of answer you expect...

Comment: of course i used css before. but the problem is id can be changable. i know that i should use id selector but id of the div is like form_id:composite_componenet_id:panel_id_header. So composite component id can be different. I want to know that you really understood the problem.

Comment: You could also give it a specific style class, then you can just add it to the CSS selector.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the `p:panel` in `<h:form prependId="false">`.

Then you can use the ID selector (as mentioned in the other reply), as the id will not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-panel-titlebar {
 //Your style-sheet code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a header facet to the panel is a good solution if you just need to change one panel. Inside the facet add any styling you require.

```
        <p:panel>
            <f:facet name="header" style="font-size: medium">
            </f:facet>
        </p:panel>
```

I avoid messing with the primefaces styling as much as possible if I just want to change individual components.